# Data validation for dependent drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm looking for the best approach to the following problem: I have a form with a number of drop down lists that are populated (or unpopulated) based off of selections made in previous drop down lists. When the lists are populated, the fields are enabled and required. When the lists are unpopulated, the fields are disabled, and thus not required. The data is being stored in a SQL database. I have applied the [Required] attribute in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to each field. This works fine on the client side, but when I try to save the model to the database, I receive dbValidationErrors for each disabled field.

Ideally, I would like to remove the [Required] attribute from the dependendent lists, allowing me to save the model to the database. Then I would just need a way to toggle a field's requirement on the client side utilizing MVC's client side validation. This would maintain consistent styling between each required field. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975809/how-to-make-a-field-required-without-data-annotation) seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for. Here's my code:

```
function enableValidation(id, formId) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('data-val-required', '');
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('data-val', 'true');
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('class', 'input-validation-error');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(formId));
}

function disableValidation(id, formId) {
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('data-val-required');
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('data-val');
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('class');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#'+formId));
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't validate when the form is submitted. Am I missing something?

I'm open to any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: If the disabled field is [Required] and you override the client validation to allow it to be empty on submit, wouldn't you expect the database to kick back an error?  Assuming the DB has the same field as required and you are sending null?

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, as expected, the database comes back with an error when a required field is sent as null. As I noted, I'm looking for a way to force client-side validation on a field that is not given the [Required] attribute.

Comment: You could use a view model and put the data annotations there instead of on your domain model.  That way, your database doesn't know about the [Required] filters.  Your client side validation would remain unchanged.  You can then perform your server side check in the controller using the ModelState properties.

Comment: @Forty-Two Thanks for the advice. Everything is submitting fine now. Post your response as an answer and I will approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per request:

You could use a view model and put the data annotations there instead of on your domain model. That way, your database doesn't know about the [Required] filters. Your client side validation would remain unchanged. You can then perform your server side check in the controller using the ModelState properties.

Comment: I usually just check ModelState.IsValid to know whether to continue the request, or return to the form and display the errors.  To access the actual values I use the model the view is typed to.